# React project not autoloading after npm start

Tags: reactjs, express, npm

I have a local copy of a react project and project still loads with npm start however I have to manually type in localhost:/8080.

1.Before It would automatically load up a webpage
2. Before it would automatically reload page when I made changes and saved.

The project still works but it is annoying to have to manually restart and make new build to see changes.  What happened?

Answer (score 0):

The package.json file under scripts had separate start:development and start:production.  I just made it "start" and it worked.

```
"scripts": {
        "start:development": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --define process.env.BASE_API='\"https:// 123.456'",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --define process.env.BASE_API='\"https://site\"'",
    }
```